# How to hide or clear a python Dash+Plotly Graph during its update

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am an absolute beginner with Dash and Plotly. I have a Graph that takes a lot of time to be updated. In this interval (the execution time of callback) I'd like to hide old version of the graph. How can I obtain this behavior?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the graph object inside a `dcc.Loading` object – https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/loading